# Gradle task failing when updating to gradle 7.3.3

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have updated my project with gradle version 7.3.3 but getting the below error: Any suggestion.

```
    Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.
```

After scan:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException: Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':compileDebugRenderscript' (type 'RenderscriptCompile').
  - In plugin 'com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile' method 'useAndroidX()' should not be annotated with: @Input.
    
    Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Remove the annotations.
      2. Rename the method.
```